# Nuget copy native dll into output

Tags: tfs, msbuild, nuget

I have my own nuget package, that contains some native dll files.

When I build project, that references the nuget package, I want all **native files from the nuget package to be copied into output directory**.

How to create such nuget pacakge that copies the files into output dir?

I've tried to use [Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output](https://github.com/baseclass/Contrib.Nuget), but I can't get it work on my Build Server (TFS 2013):

> C:\Builds\1\MyProject\BuildName\src\MyProject\Packages\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.2.1.0\build\net40\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.targets (73): The source file for this compilation can be found at: "C:\Users\MHABLDSvc\AppData\Local\Temp\fd4f7f9d-59e3-4f6a-af8c-6a48deb7af3e.txt"

> C:\Builds\1\MyProject\BuildName\src\MyProject\Packages\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.2.1.0\build\net40\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.targets (73): An error has occurred during compilation. error CS1705: Assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' uses 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

> C:\Builds\1\MyProject\BuildName\src\MyProject\Packages\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.2.1.0\build\net40\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.targets (73): The "PackageFilter" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64" directory.

> C:\Builds\1\MyProject\BuildName\src\MyProject\Packages\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.2.1.0\build\net40\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.targets (73): An error has occurred during compilation. error CS1705: Assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' uses 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

> C:\Builds\1\MyProject\BuildName\src\MyProject\Packages\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.2.1.0\build\net40\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.targets (73): The "PackageFilter" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64" directory.

Comment: Why not setting CopyLocal of your referenced assemblies in your project file?

Comment: because they are not assemblies and they are not referenced.

Comment: You can do that with any file added to your project. But then the property is named Copy to Output Directory. This would also work then for local builds.

Comment: Imagine nuget package for EmguCV for example. It contains a lof of native opencv files (hundreds of megabytes). If you add such package, would you like it to add all the files into your project? And if you had an application, that uses several such packages, it would be total mess.
The other thing is, that some people, including be does not check it nuget packages into source control, since we use automatic nuget restore during build. I want to avoid to check it tons of large files into source control, especially when they are not sources

Comment: If you're creating a package, then see https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package. You can either use `<file src="..." />` items in your .nuspec file, or add a PowerShell script if you need better copy logic (e.g. detecting if .dlls are native or not).

Comment: How  `<file src="..." />` or powershell script can help to copy files into output directory? I believe I have to add `Build\{mypackageid}.targets` into my package

Comment: @Liero: Well when you have tons of files my solution is for sure not feasible. You should state in your question that you mean "tons of large files" when you say "some native dll files" ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could write some MSBuild logic to do this.  I haven't tested this code but you could use something similar to the following (with tweaking):

```
 <Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <ItemGroup>
     <NugetDlls Include="$(SolutionDir)\packages\mypackage\**\*.dll" />
   </ItemGroup>
   <Copy SourceFiles="@(NugetDlls)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
 </Target>
```

You can even automate this change via Nuget using a [start.ps1 PowerShell script in the Tools directory](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#powershell). In this case I would create a separate .targets file with the MSBuild Target above, add it to your Nuget package and then import this targets file in the project file via the install.ps1 script. The install.ps1 would be similar to (although I haven't tested this, it may need some tweaks):

```
param($rootPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

# Add targets file to .csproj
$TargetsFile = 'AddToOutput.targets'
$path = [System.IO.Path]
$ProjectDirectory = $path::GetDirectoryName($project.FileName)
$TargetsPath = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($toolsPath, $TargetsFile)

Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

$MSBProject = [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection]::GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects($project.FullName) |
    Select-Object -First 1

$ProjectUri = New-Object -TypeName Uri -ArgumentList "file://$($project.FullName)"
$TargetUri = New-Object -TypeName Uri -ArgumentList "file://$TargetsPath"

$RelativePath = $ProjectUri.MakeRelativeUri($TargetUri) -replace '/','\'

$ExistingImports = $MSBProject.Xml.Imports |
    Where-Object { $_.Project -like "*\$TargetsFile" }
if ($ExistingImports) {
    $ExistingImports | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $MSBProject.Xml.RemoveChild($_) | Out-Null
        }
}
$MSBProject.Xml.AddImport($RelativePath) | Out-Null
$project.Save()
```

Comment: Editing the project files is a little cumbersome to maintain. "mypackage" usually always contains a versionnumber. Maybe using mypackage* would work but you have always to remember that you messed with the project file :)

Comment: You can use wildcards (i.e. "mypackage*\**\*.dl") to ignore version numbers on the package but I agree its cumbersome.  If this is a web application you can place this code in the [projectName].wpp.targets file instead to make it a bit more visible.

In the end I think this solution is your best option outside of referencing the DLLs.

Comment: I need to create nuget package that just work. I can't force people to edit their  .csproj in order to use my package.

Comment: Why not add a reference to the DLLs then?

Comment: Because they are not assemblies... you cannot add reference do native dll containing com objects.

Comment: You could add a PowerShell script to your Nuget package that will edit the project file.  Answer updated with details.